# Text cutting a pixel line out of the background

Tags: html, css, text, webkit

I'm back again with another very odd question.

What is causing the last letter "k" in the phrase to cut out a dotted line of pixels from its parent background? I have a solution, may not be the most elegant and am open to others, but I am really interested into why this is happening.

I have a scroller that I am making, right now I have just text sliding through it to test out my animation. I have tested this with letters, without a sharp edge to them, and there is no problem but with the "T and k"(possibly other letters) it cuts into the background.

The "T" Does the same effect on the top but the line is a very close blue to the background.

It works fine in Firefox and IE I am unsure since I work on a mac at home. In Chrome and Safari this problem happens.

Here is an image of how it looks,

[image: text background cut]

When you toggle the button again for the text to slide back it cuts into the background and leaves this `1px` in height cut that is dotted or a straight line.

You can also click the button again to go back over until it stops and then one more click to make a solid line cut out.

Here is the relevant `css` to what the text is contained in,

```
.text {
   right: 50%;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   font-family: "century gothic";
   position: absolute;
   color: #f7f7f7;
   transition: right 3s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition: right 3s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: right 3s ease-in;
}

.text.active {
   right: 2%;
}

.text > li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/Bc2yx/14/)  to take a peak at the code and problem.

I already have a solution to this problem right [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/Bc2yx/15/).

I used a `:before` and `:after` on the `li` to create a blank space on both sides to not cut into the background.

I appreciate any and all input on this!

Comment: [If this is the fiddle that should have the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/Bc2yx/14/), I don't see it in FF25.

Comment: The problem appears in Google Chrome but not Firefox.  However, it is worth investigating.

Comment: It also appears in Safari, sorry about not testing that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to almost certainly be a display bug. Based on the following solutions that also solved the issue, I suspect that there is a slight `1px` overlap of the *text* inside the `li` into the `ul` that shows up during the animation back causing the ghosting to happen. When I select the `li` with the inspector tool in Chrome and it highlights the selection in blue, I believe I can even see the `1px` overlap of the `k`.

I'm not sure I could give a better explanation than that--just seems to be a bug on the sizing of the `li` with the text font.

However all the following may be more elegant solutions to your issues than the pseudo-elements:

**#1 Add `padding-right: 1px`**

This worked on either the `.text` (`ul`) element ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc2yx/21/)) or the `li` element ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc2yx/22/)).

**#2 Add `overflow: hidden`**

This is to the `.text` (`ul`) element ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc2yx/23/)).

**#3 Add a right border that is transparent**

Putting a `border-right: 1px solid transparent` with a `margin-right: -1px` to offset the effect (if needed) also solve it whether on the `ul` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc2yx/24/)) or the `li` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc2yx/25/)).

**#4 Add a `margin-right: 1px`**

This only works on the `li` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc2yx/27/)).

**Conclusion**

Basically, with your original pseudo element solution and the above, it seems that anything giving a buffer to that right edge prevents the bug from happening.

Comment: Hmm what should I do now that I found a bug? I am also curious to why a letter with soft/rounded characteristics doesn't cause it, like an "h". What is there to do now? Do I have to use on of these options always or is it up to me to get them to fix it?

Comment: I think (cannot confirm) the reason it is not on rounded letters is because there is not that apparently `1px` overlap outside the `ul` container. Some of the "sharp" letters must just have their last pixel overhanging. As for reporting the bug, I would say [start here](http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html).

Comment: Thank you a ton mate! Do you think I should be worried about this with any sliding text or is it just from the structure I have the text in?

Comment: I think I have to answer your question as "just from the structure [you] have the text in," because all the solutions that I give are about changing that structure so that there is no overlap of that one pixel. If you are conscious of this possibility, then just always be sure to have something in place as given above to avoid the "bug".

Comment: Okay that is what I was assuming. Thanks again mate!